# What were the 20 airspace classes in the US before 1993?

Tags: usa, aviation-history, airspace, icao

[image]

ICAO adopted the current [airspace classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airspace_class#ICAO_definitions) in 1990. The US followed suit in 1993.

But, I found this:

> In case you didn't know, the U.S. had 20 different types of airspace designations prior to 1993. ([VATSIM](https://www.vatsim.net/pilot-resource-centre/vfr-specific-lessons/icao-airspace-classification))

- Were there really 20 classes?
- What were they and their functions?
- And if possible, how did they compare with the rest of the world pre-1990 in a general sense?

What I could find was the [Oct 1993 issue](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ube41zSkatwC) of *Flying Magazine.* From which, I couldn't find the 20 classifications, just 7 old names and some changes.

The [FAA order 7400.2D](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/10923) from 1993 includes the change, <strike>but I can't find the similar order that precedes it.</strike> The preceding document is [here](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.2C%20Basic.pdf), but unhelpful.

Also via [here](https://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/the-days-before-class-a-b-c-d-e-and-g.90984/#post-1226365) we find: **Transition Areas, Continental Control Areas, and Control Areas.** All three are now under Class E. That brings the total to 10 out of 20.

[image]

---

- Thanks to @Pondlife for the FAA document and for checking the AOPA magazine article.

Comment: I can't answer the question, but maybe the original list of 20 included special use airspace?

Comment: @Pondlife - perhaps, but SUA's still exist, which can bring the count back to 20.

Comment: Yes, that's true but I wondered if it was a deliberate or accidental piece of exaggeration, i.e. include the SUAs to make the number bigger, then exclude them to make it seem like things are now much simpler. But maybe I'm over-analyzing it :-)

Comment: The previous version of the order you mentioned is [here](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.2C%20Basic.pdf), it's from 1984. I skimmed it but didn't see any convenient table that lists all airspace types, so I'm not sure where that number comes from.

Comment: We need Terry for this!

Comment: @TomMcW - you can ping him in chat and it will notify him. Can't ping him here until he's actually answered/commented... :(

Comment: @FreeMan Yeah. I wish you could do that. He's been on quite a bit lately. Maybe he'll see the question when he's on next

Comment: I can think of 14 or so, depending upon what is considered a "class."

Comment: @TomMcW Sorry to disappoint. My memory just isn't that good, especially as I was wont to not pay proper attention to such. No problem, though, as mongo has met the need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't claim to have a definitive answer, but started listing the airspace I recall memorizing or seeing on charts.  So here's my current list:

1. Continental control
2. positive control area
3. Air defense identification zone
4. Oceanic control area (may not be USA)
5. terminal control area
6. airport surveillance area
7. tower control area
8. transition area
9. control zone
10. uncontrolled airspace
11. Military operational area
12. prohibited
13. restricted
14. alert area
15. warning area
16. caution area (1943 aeronautical chart)
17. danger area (1943 aeronautical chart)
18. airways
19. airport traffic area
20. national park
21. wildlife refuge
22. fire control area (became restricted as I recall)
23. special use area
24. laser demonstrations
25. blast area (later warning area, now TFR)
26. controlled airspace